# I'm trying to make a program that makes you lose "energy" (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that makes you lose "energy" for a game.

I made it so when you press enter you gain "energy":

```
if question == '':
    print("press enter to gain energy")



    while True:

     energyup = input()

     if energyup == "":
         energy += energygain



     print(energy)
```

I also want to make it so you lose energy every 0.5 seconds. I don't know how to do this.

I tried adding:

```
while True:
     energy -= energyloss
 print(energy)

     time.sleep(1)
```

to the bottom of the program, but that makes you lose energy WAY too fast and I don't know if there is a way to make 1 line of code sleep while everything else continues (I'm using `time.sleep` which affects the whole program) and on top of that it makes the energy gaining system just not work.

Sorry if this is a dumb question I just started learning programing and this is my first question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `time.sleep`, just check if it has been 0.5 seconds past the last time energy was lost:

```
prev_time = time.time()
while True:
    # rest of the game loop
    curr_time = time.time()
    if curr_time - prev_time > 0.5:
        energy -= energyloss
        prev_time = curr_time
```

This lets the rest of the game loop code to run concurrently.

Comment: Now how do you incorporate a blocking `input()` call into this? It's not as straightforward as you imply with that `# rest of the game loop` comment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It is quite straightforward, you just need to subtract the correct multiple of `energyloss` based on how many multiples of 0.5 seconds have occurred.

Comment: @kaya3 I think that misses the OP's desire to see the energy actively go down. Note that the OP has a `print()` call after each time when the energy goes down. And if you sat at the `input()` call indefinitely, you would "stay alive" until you provide input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use threads. Thread A is responsible for consumption, and thread B listens for input

```
energy = 0
energyloss = 1
energygain = 1
lock = threading.Lock()


def consumption():
    global energy
    while 1:
        with lock:
            energy -= energyloss
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(energy)


threading.Thread(target=consumption).start()
```

Use threading.Lock to ensure thread safety

You also need to call `with lock` when increasing energy

Comment: Multiple threads accessing shared state without any synchronization is not a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I see solution with threading which might be helpful but from your problem statement, I believe you only need to have a function that will provide the diff between the total energy accumulated and the one lost with time.

To do so, you may start a timer at the beginning and create a function that will use the current time minus the execution time to calculate the energy lost each time.

The below might be enough for you case:

```
import time

energy_gain_constant = 5
energy_loss_constant = -2
total_energy_gain = 0
start_time = time.time()

def print_total_energy():
    print(total_energy_gain + int((time.time() - start_time) / 0.5) * energy_loss_constant)


print("press enter to gain energy")
while True:
    energyup = input()
    if energyup == "":
        total_energy_gain += energy_gain_constant

    print_total_energy()
```

Adding debug logs into the method that prints how it will behave:

```
def print_total_energy():
    total_energy_lost = int((time.time() - start_time) / 0.5) * energy_loss_constant
    print(f'Total execution time: {time.time() - start_time}')
    print(f'Total energy lost: {total_energy_lost}')
    print(f'Total energy gained: {total_energy_gain}')
    print(f'Total Energy: {total_energy_gain + total_energy_lost}')
```

Output:

```
Total execution time: 12.982820272445679
Total energy lost: -50
Total energy gained: 65
Total Energy: 15
```